# Javascript table and local storage

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

How am I supposed to remove data from localStorage and remove the table through onclick function? My table that storage the localStorage item is using javascript to create (Only the row). What I want is to remove the data from a specific row and clear all the row and get back the latest storage.

Here's my code:

```
function removeItem(that){
var x = localStorage.getItem("cart");

    if(x==null){
        x = [];
    }
    else{
        x = JSON.parse(x);
    }
    x.splice(i,1);
    console.log(x);
    localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(x));
    for(var i = 1; i<=table.length; i++){
        document.getElementById("table").deleteRow(i);
    }


}
```

Comment: `x.splice(i,1);` ? What is `i` ?

Comment: index. i not sure if i do it correctly. This is the reason i am asking for help

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it's ok to use array to store data but I think it's better to use object.
For example, cart could be:

```
var cart = {
  1: {
    id: 1,
    Name: "One",
    Price: 100
  },
  2: {
    id: 2,
    Name: "Two",
    Price: 200
  }
}
```

then you could delete the cart item with id=2 with

```
delete cart[2];
```

Secondly, you can use built in functions such as getElementById, getElementsByClassName, addEventListener... to solve problem, but jquery is much more better choice for these problems.

```
document.getElementById("table")

// is equals to

$("#table")
```

shorter huh? and then you could use many more functions of jquery to cook your website your way.

A little code for your above example code
http://codepen.io/jnovax/pen/kXjGwL

Rgrds,

Comment: I want to delete the row of the table i created using javascript and the data i stored in the specific table and it is in an array that is why i am using splice. Any idea to delete from that point onwards?

Comment: show your html & js so that I could clearly see your problem plz.